# Keep trailing zeros Intl.numberformat

Tags: javascript, floating-point, formatting, numbers

I am using the following function to format some floating point numbers in a table

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en', { maximumSignificantDigits: 8}).format(data)
```

```
Price   Amount  Total
0.00009999  1.00000000  11.00000000
0.0000011   8.00000000  10.00000000
0.000001    1.00000000  2.00000000
0.00000009  1.00000000  1.00000000
```

I would like to keep the trailing zeros to give a better look at my table, as in the following example:

```
Price   Amount  Total
0.00009999  1.00000000  11.00000000
0.00000110  8.00000000  10.00000000
0.00000100  1.00000000  2.00000000
0.00000009  1.00000000  1.00000000
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `maximumSignificantDigits` to `minimumFractionDigits`:

```js
Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 8}).format(data)
```

---

Examples:

```js
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 8}).format("0.00009999"));
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 8}).format("0.000001"));
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 8}).format("0.00000100"));
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 8}).format("0.0000011"));
```